# Python3.0:-the variable which is assigned inside a path function is not readable outside it

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, global-variables

I am trying to create function which takes the path and then store it in a variable but the variable which is assigned inside a function is not readable outside it

```
def source_func(path):
    source_path=path
    print("source path is:",source_path)

source_func("C:/Users/Tools Lab1/Downloads/RBI")
source_path
```

**Actual Output:**

- function **main**.source_path(path)

**Expected Output:**

- C:/Users/Tools Lab1/Downloads/RBI

Comment: `source_path` is not a global variable. You would have to have `global source_path` at the beginning of the function to make it global.

Comment: you can return source_path from function

Comment: @Barmar Every time you use `global` a kitten dies. Please think of the kittens!

Comment: @KlausD. My answer doesn't use global, it shows how to do it correctly with returning a value. My comment just explained why his code doesn't do what he wants.

Comment: will u please explain why using global statement is not a good practice?--Klaus D

Answer (score 0):

The function should return the value, then you can assign it to the variable.

```
def source_func(path):
    source_path=path
    print("source path is:",source_path)
    return source_path

source_path = source_func("C:/Users/Tools Lab1/Downloads/RBI")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior due to "scope."  Any variable that you create inside a function is a local variable and only available inside the function. If you want it to exist outside the function, you must make it global, with the `global` statement.  But...
in general, globals are not good practice, because they can make code harder to read and debug.

There is also a hierarchy for resolving variables... It's called LEGB for short: Local, Enclosing, Global, Built-in.  Check out (Geeks for Geeks)[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-in-python-legb-rule/] for a quick overview.